# v-for dynamic video with same id tags creates error

Tags: html, vue.js, video

I am currently uploading a video file and using v-for to create video tags with the video's Url. In each tag I have the Id of "myVideo" I know I cannot have two of the same Id on a page but how can I target the correct video otherwise?

here is my code that is dynamically made.

```
<video @click="playPause" v-if="card.type == 'Video'" class="card__video" :src="card.imageurl[0]" id="myVideo"></video>
```

the method on click is:

```
playPause() {
             const myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo")
             if(myVideo.paused) {
                 myVideo.play()
             } else {
                 myVideo.pause()
             }
        }
```

I have multiple videos on my page but only the first one plays because it just targets the first video with the id="myVideo"

Comment: `@click="playPause($event)`, and then in your method `playPause($event) { const myVideo = $event.target...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default `event` object passed to the function to access the video element.

With this, you can remove the duplicated `id` attribute that you assigned to your `video` elements.

```
<video @click="playPause" v-if="card.type == 'Video'" class="card__video" :src="card.imageurl[0]"></video>
```

```
playPause(event) {
  const myVideo = event.target;
  if(myVideo.paused) {
    myVideo.play();
  } else {
    myVideo.pause();
  }
}
```

See [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/81o03552ql)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'm glad it was an easy fix!